# How to install clang-3.5 without removing gcc-4.8 on Ubuntu13.10

Tags: c++, ubuntu, gcc, c++11, clang

I want to install clang-3.5(latest version) on my desctop PC.(Ubuntu 13.10)
I've tried installation setup based on [this webpage](http://llvm.org/apt/),

The detailed steps are shown below.

1. I created the text file in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ and added the follwing lines.

   deb http://llvm.org/apt/saucy/ llvm-toolchain-saucy main
   deb-src http://llvm.org/apt/saucy/ llvm-toolchain-saucy main
2. Then, I executed following command.

   wget -O - http://llvm.org/apt/llvm-snapshot.gpg.key|sudo apt-key add -

   sudo aptitude install clang-3.5 lldb-3.5
3. I got follwing warning message. It seems to be removing gcc and clang(old version).
   But I don't want to remove gcc-4.8.

**Is it possible to install clang-3.5 without removing gcc-4.8 on Ubuntu13.10?**

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

> The following NEW packages will be installed:   clang-3.5{b}
>   libclang1-3.5{a} libobjc-4.8-dev{a} libobjc4{a} lldb-3.5{b}
>   llvm-3.5{a}    llvm-3.5-dev{a}  The following packages will be
>   upgraded:   gcc-4.8-base libasan0 libatomic1 libclang-common-3.5-dev
>   libgcc-4.8-dev libgcc1 libgomp1    libitm1 libllvm3.5 libquadmath0
>   llvm-3.5-runtime  11 packages upgraded, 7 newly installed, 0 to remove
>   and 97 not upgraded. Need to get 55.1 MB/59.2 MB of archives. After
>   unpacking 137 MB will be used. The following packages have unmet
>   dependencies:  lldb-3.5 : Breaks: lldb-3.2 but 1:3.2repack-7ubuntu1 is
>   installed.  libstdc++-4.8-dev : Depends: gcc-4.8-base (=
>   4.8.1-10ubuntu9) but 4.8.2-1ubuntu1 is to be installed.
>                        Depends: libgcc-4.8-dev (= 4.8.1-10ubuntu9) but 4.8.2-1ubuntu1 is to be installed.  g++-4.8 : Depends: gcc-4.8-base (= 4.8.1-10ubuntu9) but 4.8.2-1ubuntu1 is to be installed.  clang-3.5 : Breaks: clang-3.2 but 1:3.2repack-7ubuntu1 is installed.  libstdc++6 :
>   Depends: gcc-4.8-base (= 4.8.1-10ubuntu9) but 4.8.2-1ubuntu1 is to be
>   installed.  cpp-4.8 : Depends: gcc-4.8-base (= 4.8.1-10ubuntu9) but
>   4.8.2-1ubuntu1 is to be installed.  gcc-4.8 : Depends: gcc-4.8-base (= 4.8.1-10ubuntu9) but 4.8.2-1ubuntu1 is to be installed.
>              Depends: libgcc-4.8-dev (= 4.8.1-10ubuntu9) but 4.8.2-1ubuntu1 is to be installed. open: 66; closed: 203; defer: 25; conflict: 34
>   .The following actions will resolve these dependencies:
>
> **Remove the following packages:
>
>   1)      clang
>
>   2)      clang-3.2
>
>   3)      g++
>
>   4)      g++-4.8
>
>   5)      gcc
>
>   6)      gcc-4.8
>
>   7)      lldb-3.2**
>   Upgrade the following packages:
>   8)      cpp-4.8 [4.8.1-10ubuntu9 (now, saucy-updates) ->
>   4.8.2-1ubuntu1 (saucy)]           9)      libstdc++-4.8-dev [4.8.1-10ubuntu9 (now, saucy-updates) -> 4.8.2-1ubuntu1 (saucy)] 10)
>   libstdc++6 [4.8.1-10ubuntu9 (now, saucy-updates) -> 4.8.2-1ubuntu1
>   (saucy)]        Leave the following dependencies unresolved:
>   11)     cmake recommends gcc
>   12)     ubuntu-desktop recommends gcc
>   Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?]

Comment: Why not askubuntu.com?

Comment: they just barely started on 3.5 so I wouldnt jump on board with that just yet, their website is in a bit of limbo 3.4 was supposed to be released last month, and now it shows 3.3 stable, on to 3.5 but 3.4 is not mentioned anywhere.  you can download and build it though

Comment: @Etherealone Sorry if my question is inappropriate here. But I tried to ask the same question in askubuntu.com. I could't post it because of the lack of reputation.

Answer (score 3):

change the 34 to 35 and may have to add a sudo or two in there.

```
export JN
#export JN='-j 8'

svn co http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/llvm/branches/release_34/ llvm34
cd llvm34
cd tools
svn co http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/cfe/branches/release_34/ clang
cd ..
./configure --enable-optimized --disable-doxygen --prefix=/opt/llvm34
make $JN
make install
```

then add /opt/llvm3x/bin to your path if you want to use it, otherwise dont add the path.

What clang/llvm has to do with gcc I have no idea they are two completely separate things just like having vi and emacs installed at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You can install clang from source (http://clang.llvm.org/get_started.html) anywhere in your disk without affecting other versions of clang that are installed.

Then append the PATH variable in the `~/.bashrc`:

```
export PATH=/path/to/install/clang/bin:$PATH
```

or, you can use the clang using the full-path like this:

```
/path/to/install/clang/bin/clang -c test.cpp
```